# a picker list in android

Tags: android, menu, picker

This might be due to my English limitations, but I'm looking for the correct button that, when pressed, opens a list of pre-defined options. For example, before it is pressed it displays the first country on the alphabet, and when pressed, opens a list of other countries to choose from.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the spinner.

Unlike the iOS, the picker refers to date and time pickers only in Android.